# How to prepare 2-bromobutane from 1-butanol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

So my answer (g then b) was incorrect. I thought that the bulky strong base of b would do E2 on 2-bromobutane, making it but-1-ene, then just add $\ce{HBr}$. What is wrong with my way of thinking?

Comment: That you’re starting with butan-1-**ol.** Alcohols don’t eliminate easily.

Comment: $\ce{OH-}\mathbf{\neq good~leaving~group.}$

Answer (score 2):

The hydroxyl fragment isn't a good leaving group, unless the medium is acidic. Using just HBr, you can convert the hydroxyl group into an oxonium ion (the H2O fragment would be a good leaving group). Upon heterolysis of the C-O bond, a hydride shift occurs simultaneously to create a secondary carbocation. The exogenous bromide can act as a nucleophile towards the secondary carbocation to form 2-bromobutane.

Comment: Apart from a few weird references and those that include spacy catalysts, **reacting an alcohol with $\ce{HBr}$ gives the corresponding bromide from the $\mathrm{S_N2}$ mechanism** thus in this case 1-bromobutane. That corresponds to my experience using $\ce{HI}$ where I got 1-iodobutane exclusively in near-quantitative yield.

Comment: when I was a graduate student, I TA'ed organic lab where the students had to do this exact experiment. If my memory serves me correctly, they got a mixture of both.

Comment: Scratch the previous comment, the experiment the students had to do was very similar, but not exactly the same.

Comment: right. So the first step would be using HBr to form an oxonium ion. Can you describe the hydride shift afterwards? I'm a little confused on that. Would the H2O just leave since it's a good LG and then one of the beta hydrogens going over to where the H2O left? Then there will be a secondary carbocation and Br- attacks there?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c7dnaqgmhac2iuc/bromo%20ex.pdf?dl=0. Copy and paste the url to see what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

$\ce{(CH3)3COK}$ reacts with $\ce{R-X}$ to give a Hoffman alkene.
Elimination of the OH group usually requires protonation of oxygen, which requires an acidic medium.

A good solution to the given problem would be to add HBr without peroxide, which will give SN$_2$ (no rearrangement, i.e. no cation shift) and give us $\ce{CH3CH2CH2CH2Br}$.

Then, add $\ce{(CH3)3COK/(CH3)3COH}$ to get but-1-ene. Then, add HBr to get 2-bromobutane.

Also a useful sidenote is that methanol, ethanol, n-propanol, and n-butanol all undergo SN$_2$ when reacted with $\ce{HX}$. Other alcohols undergo SN$_1$.